# How to use django chartit chart object in template

Tags: django

I am trying to create line charts using django chartit. Steps done are ,
I have created new app in django and used the code from http://chartit.shutupandship.com/docs/#how-to-create-charts and placed in 'views.py' and rendered the chart object to template( like,  return render_to_response('values.html', {'mychart': cht}))

Chart object has the values retrieved from database tables.

'Highcharts' ( used with chartit) example from http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ is using hard coded data. (x Axis , y Axis values) , which is,

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }
 series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]}
```

But , I want to use the chart object data in template and create the chart using those values using jquery code ( in a java script).
I have tried like ..series, which is giving single element. I am not able to find a way to use this value in template.

Comment: I have tried like chart_object_name.datapool_object_name.series, giving single element as o/p in template

Comment: I checked that chart object passed to template is getting correct values ( database values) .so, no need to read the chart object data in template. 
Now ,issue is ,the values for y-Axis are string values separated by comma in my database (say "45.6,67.8"). As line chart don't accept these values, I have retrived the data from models and changed from string to float format ,then  passed  that 'queryset' as 'source' to 'Datapool' object.
chartit is taking as string format only. When giving queryset, how do I give the 'terms' to access fields from queryset. giving field names is not working.